# XMPP Smack can not receive the message

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I read lots of related posts about how to send and receive message by smack 4.1
and openFire  . from my understanding i implemented the following code

I can connect, i can login . but when sending message form **user1 to user2** i get nothing.

**code:**

```
package passargad.ehsan;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.chat.ChatMessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XMPPservice extends Service {   
    XMPPTCPConnection connection;    
    String connectionMessages="";  
    ConnectionXMPP connectionXMPPAsynch =new ConnectionXMPP();

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            connectionXMPPAsynch.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    class ConnectionXMPP extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setServiceName("192.168.1.6").setUsernameAndPassword("ehsan", "123")
                    .setPort(9090).setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setCompressionEnabled(false).build());
            connection.setUseStreamManagement(true);
            connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {
                    Log.d("connected", "yes connected successfully : ");

                }

                @Override
                public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
                    Log.d("connected","yes authenticated successfully : ");
                }

                @Override
                public void connectionClosed() {
                    Log.d("connected","yes connectionClosed successfully : ");
                }

                @Override
                public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {

                    Log.d("connected","yes connectionClosedOnError  : ");
                    connectionMessages="connectionClosedOnError";
                    publishProgress();

                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                    Log.d("connected","yes reconnection successfully : ");
                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                    Log.d("connected","yes reconnectingIn  : ");
                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("connected","yes reconnectionFailed  : ");
                }
            });

            connect();
            chat();





            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if (connectionMessages=="connectionClosedOnError")
            {    
                connect();    
            }    
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.d("","onPostExecute");
        }

        private void connect()
        {

            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login();
                Log.d(""," user id  ::   " + connection.getUser());

            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        private void chat()
        {

            ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("192.168.1.6" ,new ChatMessageListener() {
                @Override
                public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

                    Log.d("","message :"+  message.getBody());
                }
            });   
            try
            {

                Message newMessage = new Message();
                newMessage.setBody("Howdy!");
                newMessage.setFrom("ehsan@192.168.1.6/Smack");
                newMessage.setTo("ehsan@192.168.1.6/Smack");
                newChat.sendMessage(newMessage);



            }
            catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            chatmanager.addChatListener(
                    new ChatManagerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally)
                        {
                            if (!createdLocally)
                                chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                                        Log.d("","message :"+  message.getBody());
                                    }
                                });;
                        }
                    });

        }

    }

}
```

**here is the logcat:**

> ```
> 02-20 06:45:13.334    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent
> 02-20 06:45:13.334    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13351: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
> 02-20 06:45:13.334    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
> 02-20 06:45:13.334    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x0009-0011 in Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent;)V
> 02-20 06:45:13.344    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;)
> 02-20 06:45:13.344    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo
> 02-20 06:45:13.344    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13352: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;)V
> 02-20 06:45:13.344    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
> 02-20 06:45:13.344    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x0009-0011 in Landroid/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutCompat;.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;)V
> 02-20 06:45:13.374    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan I/KeyCharacterMap﹕ No keyboard for id -1
> 02-20 06:45:13.374    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan I/KeyCharacterMap﹕ Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
> 02-20 06:45:13.504    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 46% free 3077K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+11ms
> 02-20 06:45:16.858    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 263K, 44% free 3317K/5895K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+6ms
> 02-20 06:45:17.088    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 252K, 43% free 3485K/6087K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+6ms
> 02-20 06:45:17.208    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed, referenced from method de.measite.minidns.Client.query
> 02-20 06:45:17.208    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14707: Ljava/lang/Throwable;.addSuppressed (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
> 02-20 06:45:17.208    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x006f
> 02-20 06:45:17.208    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed, referenced from method de.measite.minidns.Client.query
> 02-20 06:45:17.208    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14707: Ljava/lang/Throwable;.addSuppressed (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x009d
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed, referenced from method de.measite.minidns.Client.query
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14707: Ljava/lang/Throwable;.addSuppressed (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00b4
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x0072-0072 in Lde/measite/minidns/Client;.query (Lde/measite/minidns/Question;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lde/measite/minidns/DNSMessage;
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x00a0-00a0 in Lde/measite/minidns/Client;.query (Lde/measite/minidns/Question;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lde/measite/minidns/DNSMessage;
> 02-20 06:45:17.218    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x00b7-00b7 in Lde/measite/minidns/Client;.query (Lde/measite/minidns/Question;Ljava/lang/String;I)Lde/measite/minidns/DNSMessage;
> 02-20 06:45:17.428    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 273K, 42% free 3647K/6279K, external 0K/0K, paused 4ms+6ms
> 02-20 06:45:17.688    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 403K, 44% free 3652K/6407K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+5ms
> 02-20 06:45:17.979    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/connected﹕ yes connected successfully :
> 02-20 06:45:18.519    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 323K, 42% free 3739K/6407K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+6ms
> 02-20 06:45:18.669    1188-1193/passargad.ehsan I/dalvikvm﹕ Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
> 02-20 06:45:18.779    1188-1193/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ null clazz in OP_INSTANCE_OF, single-stepping
> 02-20 06:45:19.460    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 479K, 43% free 3737K/6535K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+6ms
> 02-20 06:45:20.221    1188-1190/passargad.ehsan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 486K, 43% free 3742K/6535K, external 0K/0K, paused 5ms+6ms
> 02-20 06:45:20.371    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/connected﹕ yes authenticated successfully :
> 02-20 06:45:20.391    1188-1199/passargad.ehsan D/﹕ user id  ::   ehsan@passargad-pc/Smack
> 02-20 06:45:20.411    1188-1188/passargad.ehsan D/﹕ onPostExecute
> ```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look through the code, I found a few mistakes:

1. createChat expects the first argument to be userJid (not host IP)

   ```
   Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("ehsan@<service name>" ,new ChatMessageListener() {
       @Override
       public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
           Log.d("","message :"+  message.getBody());
       }
   });
   ```
2. Enable debugging and check logs

   ```
   connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(
           XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                   .setServiceName("192.168.1.6")
                   .setUsernameAndPassword("ehsan", "123")
                   .setPort(9090)
                   .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                   .setCompressionEnabled(false)
                   .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                   .build());
   ```
3. Change port from 9090 to 5222 (In case you didn't change default configuration; check openfire admin panel)
4. Prefer using `addAsyncStanzaListener` to listen for incoming packets.

Comment: thank you for your comment.  is the jid you said "ehsan@192.168.1.9/Smack"  if not could you please let me know  what should be placed for service name

Comment: when i get userJID  it is ehsan@passargad-pc/Smack.  the passargad-pc is my laptop which openfire is running on. and its local ip is 192.168.1.6.

Comment: in the createChat should  username be receiver username?

Comment: i found the problem. as you said service name should not be host ip. in the openfire admin i found server name which was "passargad-pc" i searched and from this link [difference between XMPP servername and XMPP servicename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193236/difference-between-xmpp-servername-and-xmpp-servicename) i found that server name and service name are the same

Comment: but now another question raised : i test by both ports 9090 and 5222 and it worked. so why is that?

Comment: That's new. By default, 9090 is for admin panel, 5222 is for TCP connection, and 7070 for BOSH connection. I'll have to look into why both of them work, but until then prefer 5222 only :)

Answer (score 0):

This example may be useful for you:

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws XMPPException {
        ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 5222);    
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config); 
        connection.connect();   
        connection.login("userx", "123456");
        ChatManager cm = connection.getChatManager(); 
        Chat chat = cm.createChat("tongqian@tsw-PC", null);
        /*
         * add listener
         */
        cm.addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean create) {
                chat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
                        System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() + ":" + msg.getBody());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        chat.sendMessage("hello");  
        while(true);        
        //connection.disconnect();  
    }
}
```